# Question on Do Carmo Diff Geo about Gaussian Maps

Tags: differential-geometry

I am currently studying Do Carmo's differential Geometry of curves and surfaces and I have two questions from the 3rd section which is about Gaussian maps.

1. Show that if a surface is tangent to a plane along a curve, then the points of this curve are either parabolic or planar.

I think that if $N$ is the Gauss map, and $\alpha(t)$ is the curve, then $N(\alpha(t))$ is normal to the plane and hence constant. Thus $0≡dN/dt=dN(\alpha′(t))$ all points of the curve. But I cannot continue anymore. Any help is appreciated.

2. Show that the sum of the normal curvatures for any pair of orthogonal direc-
   tions, at a point $p\in S$, is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to the first question is correct. The Gauss map is a mapping $G: M \rightarrow S^2$
from the surface M to the unit sphere $S^2$. It is important to distinguish between Gauss map and unit normal. Suppose that $X:F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, where F is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, parametrizes a neighborhood of M, then the function $U:F \rightarrow S^2$ is defined in reference to the parametrization X as
\begin{equation}
U = \frac{X_u \times X_v}{||X_u \times X_v||}
\end{equation}
U is the unit normal. The Gauss map  and U are related by the fact that if the parametrization is oriented positively
\begin{equation}
U = G \circ X
\end{equation}
You wrote, correctly, that the differential of the Gauss map along the curve $\alpha(t)$ is zero, because N is  normal  to  the  plane  and  hence constant. The differential of the Gauss map, at a point p, where $p \in M$, is a linear transformation $dN_p:T_pM \rightarrow T_pM$. The differential of the Gauss map satisfies the equation
\begin{equation}
dN/dt=dN(\alpha′(t))=0
\end{equation}
Assuming $\alpha$ is a regular parametrization, $\alpha'(t) \neq 0$ and so $ker(dN) \neq 0$, where ker is the kernel. Thus $dN_p$ is not injective (a linear transformation is injective if and only if its kernel is null) and so $det(dN_p) = 0$. Now if $det(dN_p) = 0$ but  $dN_p \neq 0$ we have parabolic points. If $det(dN_p) = 0$ and  $dN_p = 0$ we have planar points.

Consider now the eigenvalues of the shape operator $k_1$ and $k_2$. Let $u_1$ be a unit eigenvector for M with
eigenvalue  $k_1$ i.e. $dN_p(u_1) = k_1 u_1$ . Let $u_2$ be the unit tangent vector rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise from $u_1$, i.e. $dN_p(u_2) = k_2 u_2$. A unit vector u may be written as
\begin{equation}
u= u_1 \cos(\theta) + u_2 \sin(\theta)
\end{equation}
where $\theta$ is the angle between u and $u_1$. e may now compute the normal curvature $k_n$ at u as
\begin{equation}
k_n(\theta) = -dN_p(u) \cdot u = -dN_p(u_1 \cos(\theta) + u_2 \sin(\theta)) \cdot (u_1 \cos(\theta) + u_2 \sin(\theta))= -(\cos(\theta) dN_p(u_1)+ \sin(\theta) dN_p(u_2)) \cdot (u_1 \cos(\theta) + u_2 \sin(\theta)) =
-(\cos(\theta) u_1 k_1 + \sin(\theta) u_2 k_2) \cdot (u_1 \cos(\theta) + u_2 \sin(\theta)) = -(\cos^2(\theta) |u_1|^2 k_1+ \sin^2(\theta) |u_2|^2 k_2)= -(\cos^2(\theta)  k_1+ \sin^2(\theta) k_2)
\end{equation}
where I use the fact that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are ortogonal and that $u_1$ and $u_2$  are unit eigenvectors. Now two unit vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ in the orthogonal directions are such that
\begin{equation}
k_n(v_1) = -(\cos^2(v_1)  k_1+ \sin^2(v_1) k_2)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
k_n(v_2) = -(\sin^2(v_2)  k_1+ \cos^2(v_2) k_2)
\end{equation}
Then 
\begin{equation}
k_n(v_1)+k_n(v_2) = - (k_1+k_2)= -2H =\frac{1}{2} Tr(dN_p)  
\end{equation}

Comment: $K_n$ should be in small case?

Comment: Usually K in capital letter is used for the Gaussian curvature, $k_n$ in small letter for the normal curvature, $k_g$ in small letter for the geodesic curvature. I modified the answer according to this notation.

Comment: Thanks about taking suggestion.